# Fetching particular data from Firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to fetch data from Firebase. Here's the database structure :

Database Snap Shot below

[image]

I want to retrieve only the PartyName and ID. My code is like this :

```
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    firebase = new Firebase("https://login-b3a11.firebaseio.com/Users");
    //  com.firebase.client.Query query=firebase.orderByChild("Date").equalTo("ID");
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(Status.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listGet);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    firebase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Get g= (Get) ds.getValue();
                listGet.add(g.getPartyName());
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
```

and `Get` is a class which has getter and setter method. But my app crashes.

**Logcat**

```
12-24 13:40:11.010 2134-3707/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=490, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
12-24 13:40:11.132 2134-3707/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=491, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
12-24 13:40:11.330 20641-20641/? E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
                                                java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzeh(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
                                                    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
                                                    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5174)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4769)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4709)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1415)
                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzz(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzaa; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa' appears in /data/app/com.example.amisha.login-2/base.apk)
                                                    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzx.zzbd(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
                                                    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzeh(Unknown Source) 
                                                    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748) 
                                                    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723) 
                                                    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5174) 
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4769) 
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4709) 
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1415) 
                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
12-24 13:40:11.513 20672-20672/? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power
```

Comment: can u please post logcat

Comment: Is the code correct?

Comment: Probably your app is crashing because of this `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);` line. Try to make your custom class which should extend Application class and there you should write that line. One more thing, this syntax of using Firebase is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will help you to get ride of new way of implementation
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-working-with-firebase-realtime-database/
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to get reference to your database the right way. Remove these two lines from your code:

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
firebase = new Firebase("https://login-b3a11.firebaseio.com/Users");
//  com.firebase.client.Query
```

replace them with this

```
FirebaseDatbase mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mMessagesDatabaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
```

You can now use the `DatabaseReference` object which is called `mMessagesDatabaseRefrence` to send your query.

Comment: @ashish-ahuja is it `Database`? or `DatabaseReference`? Because as far as I know, `getReference()` method returns `DatabaseReference` object

Comment: @rmn I do not know, I'm not proficient with this language. The reason why I rollbacked your edit was because you were putting words in the authors mouth which is wrong. You can put a comment, or put your own answer (giving reference to this answer if you took something from it) with the change if you want though. TL;DR, do not make edits **which change the actual meaning of the answer**, whether the edit is wrong or right.

Comment: You are right i made a mistake it is called DatabaseRefrence

Answer (score 0):

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.amisha.login, PID: 4849
                                                 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.amisha.login.Get
                                                     at com.example.amisha.login.Status$1.onChildAdded(Status.java:52)
                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahh.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajh.zzctc(Unknown Source)
                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajk$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-24 16:05:25.710 5445-5445/? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
12-24 16:05:25.711 5445-5445/? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
12-24 16:05:30.734 5463-5463/? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
12-24 16:05:30.735 5463-5463/? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
12-24 16:05:35.752 5464-5464/? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
12-24 16:05:35.753 5464-5464/? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
12-24 16:05:36.425 2134-3707/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=512, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
12-24 16:05:37.045 5489-5489/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(847): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
12-24 16:05:37.351 2134-4459/? E/LocSvc_IzatApiV02: E/virtual int izat_core::IzatApiV02::getBatchSize(int32_t):620]: Error : st = 4, ind.status = -1600126925
12-24 16:05:37.351 2134-4459/? E/LocSvc_IzatApiV02: E/virtual int izat_core::IzatApiV02::getBatchSize(int32_t):633]: get batching size failed.Or modem does not support batching 
12-24 16:05:37.507 2134-3707/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=514, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_
```

I got this now. Tried code is :

```
 listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://login-b3a11.firebaseio.com/Users");
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
       final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listGet);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
       mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onChildAdded(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
               for(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                   Get g=new Get();
                   g=(Get)ds.getValue();
                   myadapter.add(g.getPartyName());
                   arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               }
           }
```

Comment: how does this answer address the question?

Comment: @Atika, I think you should just edit the question and not post update as answer. That will make it more confusing. By the way, keep your coding spirit :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are casting it in a wrong way.Do this in onChildAdded

```
 @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Get g= ds.getValue(Get.class);
            listGet.add(g.getPartyName());
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseDatabase database ;
```

instanse create on onCreate

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

DatabaseReference dbOrderReference = database.getReference("Users/" +"001");
dbOrderReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  //get id and phone_number
  String id=String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue());
  String phone_num=String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("PhoneNo").getValue());

 }
 @Override
 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

 }
});
```